# Insert input values in JSON Array-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a Json Array. I need to append the values when form is submitted. But it says its undefined. Please tell me where I am wrong.

**HTML**

```
<form class="inputSection">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter title(Ex: My Newyork Experience)" id="titleName"/>
            <textarea placeholder="Tell us more about it. (Ex: When I went to Newyork...)" id="titleDesc"></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick="submitForm()"/>
        </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function submitForm(){
var titleInput=document.getElementById('titleName').value;
var messageInput=document.getElementById('titleDesc').value;

var objJSON=[
                {
                    "title": "This is my title",
                    "desc": "This is my message"
                },
                {
                    "title":titleInput ,
                    "desc": messageInput
                }
            ];
for(i=0; i<=objJSON.length-1;i++){
    alert(objJSON[i].title);
    alert(objJSON[i].desc);            
}
}
```

Let me know how to append the values inserted to the array object.

Comment: Your code representation of the issue is incomplete, but apparently those elements do not have a `.value` property. Can't tell you why without the HTML markup.

Comment: ...and of course, that isn't JSON until/unless you serialize it as JSON.

Comment: "it says its undefined" — What says this? What is it saying is undefined?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: What is your expected output... [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9bAz/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggesstions. I solved it... Used serailization